# Node.js - Understanding and Limiting Memory Usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am in the process of running multiple Node applications on a single instance. One of the elements I am concerned about is memory usage. Is there a minimum amount of physical memory required by a simple Node.js express service?  Is there a way I can set an upper bound on the memory usage to prevent one of my node applications from affecting the others use of physical memory?

Comment: my historical minimum for node itself (with an app running) has been about 10mb/instance. even on a 32-core box, that's only 320mb of ram unless you're spinning up more than one per cpu.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to spin up more than one per CPU? I was planning on this.

Comment: the main advantage to running more than one instance stems from running each single-thread JS core on it's own CPU. there are potentially other minor managerial benefits to segmentation, but above 1:1 performance actually drops as middle-management consumes more resources switching.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth your while to put your node processes on docker instance.  Might just start with the default [node docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/node/) and then add your source code and boot up the scripts in the Dockerfile.

Docker allows you to limit the memory of each Docker instance, and many Docker instances can run on a single machine (or Virtual Machine).  I think this approach might be your best bet.

Comment: I actually am using docker. I didn't know Docker had the ability to limit memory. Can you provide more details on this specific aspect?

Comment: ya, check this out: https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory